# Julia : BLAS.gemm!() parameters

Tags: julia, blas

I want to use the BLAS package. To do so, the meaning of the two first parameters of the `gemm()` function is not evident for me.
What do the parameters `'N'` and `'T'` represent?

```
 BLAS.gemm!('N', 'T', lr,  alpha, A, B, beta, C)
```

What is the difference between `BLAS.gemm` and `BLAS.gemm!` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/linalg/#module-Base.LinAlg.BLAS)

> **gemm!(tA, tB, alpha, A, B, beta, C)**
>
> Update C as alpha * A * B + beta*C or the other three variants according to tA (transpose A) and tB. Returns the updated C.

Note: here, `alpha` and `beta` must be `float` type scalars. `A`, `B` and `C` are all matrices.  It's up to you to make sure the matrix dimensions match.

Thus, the `tA` and `tB` parameters refer to whether you want to apply the transpose operation to `A` or to `B` before multiplying.  Note that this will cost you some computation time and allocations - the transpose isn't free. (thus, if you were going to apply the multiplication many times, each time with the same transpose specification, you'd be better off storing your matrix as the transposed version from the beginning).  Select `N` for no transpose, `T` for transpose.  You must select one or the other.

The difference between `gemm!()` and `gemv!()` is that for `gemm!()` you already need to have allocated the matrix `C`.  The `!` is a "modify in place" signal.  Consider the following illustration of their different uses:

```
A = rand(5,5)
B = rand(5,5)
C = Array(Float64, 5, 5)

BLAS.gemm!('N', 'T', 1.0, A, B, 0.0, C)
D = BLAS.gemm('N', 'T', 1.0, A, B)

julia> C == D
true
```

Each of these, in essence, perform the calculation C = A * B'.  (Technically, `gemm!()` performs C = (0.0)*C + (1.0)*A * B'.)

Thus, the syntax for the modify in place `gemm!()` is a bit unusual in some respects (unless you've already worked with a language like C in which case it seems very intuitive).  You don't have the explicit `=` sign like you frequently do when calling functions in assigning values in a high level object oriented language like Julia.

As the illustration above shows, the outcome of `gemm!()` and `gemm()` in this case is identical, even though the syntax and procedure to achieve that outcome is a bit different.  Practically speaking, however, performance differences between the two can be significant, depending on your use case.  In particular, if you are going to be performing that multiplication operation many times, replacing/updating the value of `C` each time, then `gemm!()` can be a decent bit quicker because you don't need to keep re-allocating new memory each time, which does have time costs, both in the initial memory allocation and then in the garbage collection later on.

Comment: Thank you for this clever clarification

Comment: but l still don't understand 'N' , 'T' . Any clarifications please ? 

TRANSA = 'N' or 'n',  op( A ) = A.

 TRANSA = 'T' or 't',  op( A ) = A'.

TRANSB = 'N' or 'n',  op( B ) = B.

 TRANSB = 'T' or 't',  op( B ) = B'.

 TRANSB = 'C' or 'c',  op( B ) = B'.

Comment: @samtzaurtis `op( )` refers to a generic operation, in this case either "transpose" or "nothing".  (the reason for the somewhat confusing terminology is that there are some other operations that can be specified in other BLAS functions and for other types of matrices, so in there, `op()` can have > 2 possible values).  Thus, when it says ` TRANSA = 'N' or 'n', op( A ) = A` it means that the "operation" that you're specifying is just nothing, or more technically, you could call it the identity transformation, since `A` will be "transformed" but will just leave it exactly as `A`